# What does this symbol < > means in Salesforce Validation Rules?

Tags: salesforce

I gone through one validation rule where I saw <> this symbol. Can anyone let me know what is this symbol stands for.

Regards,
Dhanashri P.

Answer (score 2):

"Not equals", alternative way of writing `!=`.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5 (in "logical operators" section)

I think they did it to make move to validation rules simpler for people who are used to MS Excel.
Similarly you can write boolean logic "programmer style" (`condition1 && condition2 || condition3`) or Excel-like (`OR(AND(condition1, condition2), condition3)`).